# C# ef core efficiently determine if there is only one row in a query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

What is the most efficient way to check if a particular query has one row AND only one row?
.FirstOrDefault() will not serve my purpose because I am interested in knowing if there are two+ or just one result.

is it

1. via count async

```
var record = await _FilteredContext.Context.Where(x => x.Criterion == FilterCondition).CountAsync();
var singular = record == 1;
```

2. 

```
var singular = false;
try
{
 var record = await _FilteredContext.Context.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Criterion == 
 FilterCondition);
 singular = true;
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
```

or something else entirely?

Comment: That's highly db dependent and how the query to the db looks. Take a look at the generated sql and the explainplan of that.

Comment: `.SingelOrDefault` will return one by definition so you never know from that > 1

Comment: Why not run benchmarks?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it will throw an exception if there is more than one row.

Comment: @Ralf that's sort of the point

Comment: Do you only want the number of records in the result set or is the content important as well? (first case: only select 1 column instead of all).

Comment: @Ralf Yes, but that is different than > 1 perhaps; I guess that depends upon your viewpoint.  But the OP does not state if they want to know if there are "any" also

Comment: For that second query you need to check  the specific exception and not make the assumption there.  Check for `InvalidOperationException` specifically as that indicates the input sequence contains more than one element.

Comment: For that first case you should probably check if the source or predicate is null or it could throw an `ArgumentNullException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same technique as any ORMs do - take two records and apply `Count`.

```cs
var count = await _FilteredContext.Context
        .Where(x => x.Criterion == FilterCondition)
        .Take(2)
        .CountAsync();
var singular = count == 1;
```

Comment: You should probably check if the source or predicate is null or it could throw an ArgumentNullException on the `Where`

Answer (score 1):

You have three options, and it depends on if you want to know exactly what number of results you get, and if you want exceptions to direct the flow of logic.

First is to use `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault`). This will throw an exception if you get more than 1 result (`SingleOrDefault` will not throw with 0 results).

```
YourModelType resultingObject;
try
{
    resultingObject = await _FilteredContext.Context
        .Single(x => x.Criterion == FilterCondition);
}
catch
{
    // (assuming another error wasn't thrown)
    // do something if more than one result
}
```

Under the hood, at least for Sql Server, this translates to (roughly)

```sql
select top 2 *
from YourTable
where Criterion == <param>
```

The reason why this SQL is generated is to prevent fetching and searching extra rows. 2 is the minimum number to check for the row count to determine if you got "more than one" result. There's no point in passing back *all* rows to the client if passing back a maximum of 2 rows is sufficient.

The second option is to make this yourself. This will only work if you *only* care about if there are 0, 1, or "more than 1" results.

```
var queryCount = await _FilteredContext.Context
    .Where(x => x.Criterion == FilterCondition)
    .Take(2)
    .CountAsync();
```

You can swap out `CountAsync` with `ToListAsync` if you want the objects. Then you just need some logic to determine how many results you have, it's either going to be 0, 1, or 2.

Third option is to keep what you have. This is used if you want to know *exactly* how many records you get, even if it's "more than 1".

Comment: You should probably check if the source or predicate is null or it could throw an `ArgumentNullException` on the `Where`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, check if `Context` is null? Check if `FilterCondition` is null? And plus, that's not really the point of this question.

Comment: Yes, yes and as you imply the OP's code has this same challenge also.  Comment more for for others later who may choose to utilize your good answer.  You can also isolate in that first example for `ArgumentNullException` which is likely slightly less efficient than a null check and that specific `InvalidOperationException` for the `Single` if the OP cares not if it has 0 or > 1.